# Convert gl_FragCoord coordinate to screen positions

Tags: opengl, shader, fragment-shader

I'm strictly talking about a 2d environment (in fact this is for a 2d game).

In a fragment shader, how can I convert gl_FragCoord.x and gl_FragCoord.y to screen coordinates so that the top-left pixel is 0, 0 and the bottom right is the screen resolution (for example 800, 600)? Thanks

Answer (score 6, accepted):

By default the origin is at the bottom left and pixels are centered at half integer coordinates (the bottom left pixel is at (0.5, 0.5)). One way to achieve what you want is to redeclare `gl_FragCoord` with a layout qualifier:

```
layout(origin_upper_left) in vec4 gl_FragCoord;
```

or

```
layout(origin_upper_left, pixel_center_integer) in vec4 gl_FragCoord;
```

if you want the pixels to be centered on integer coordinates.

Another way is to pass in the screen resolution in a uniform variable and do a bit of math:

```
vec2 pos = vec2(gl_FragCoord.x, resolution.y - gl_FragCoord.y);
```

or to get integer values:

```
vec2 pos = vec2(gl_FragCoord.x, resolution.y - gl_FragCoord.y) - 0.5;
```

Note that if you want the pixels centered on integer coordinates then the pixel at the corner opposite the origin will be `resolution - 1.0` not `resolution`.